# How to make a list of strings with a for loop

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, append

Assume I have a `list=[1,2,3,4]` then I want to make a list of strings which length of each string associated with corresponding value in a list.

It means the final output should be like this:

```
strs=['1', '11', '111', '1111']
```

I tried the code below but I am not sure how to continue.

```
lis=[1,2,3,4]
strs=[]
for i in range (len(lis)):
    st=lis[i]
    strs.append(st)
```

Comment: Your current code just copies the list.

Comment: `['1' * i for i in range(1, 5)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplication for strings is repetition, so:

```
lst=[1,2,3,4]

result = []
for e in lst:
    result.append('1'*e)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['1', '11', '111', '1111']
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to loop over the list of lengths **lis**

Then in each iteration looping ***n*** times (the given length of that iteration) and appending **1** each time to the **newStr**.

And after the iteration adding the **newStr** to the list **strs**

```
lis = [1,2,3,4]
strs = []
for n in lis:
    newStr = ""
    for x in range(n):
        newStr += str('1')
    strs.append(newStr)
```